# Gradle buildEnvironment for project in nested directory?

Tags: java, gradle

If I clone github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot and run `./gradlew  buildEnvironment`, I will get a list of about 20 dependencies. But they are not for the nested projects. That's cool.

But I want to know which version of embedded tomcat the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` project is using. If I do either of these, I get the same empty result:

```
./gradlew -b ./spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/build.gradle buildEnvironment

./gradlew -p ./spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-tomcat buildEnvironment
```

How can I get a list of the dependencies, with versions, of spring-boot-starter-tomcat?